# Changing object variable address in function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got very basic function

```
  defineSpeciality() {
        for (var i=0; i<this.readyOffer.speciality.length; i++) {
          output = output  + this.readyOffer.speciality[i].name + ', '
        }
      return output
  },
```

I want to be able to pass the parameter inside my function and change `this.readyOffer.speciality.length` into for example `this.readyOffer.experience.length`

so my function should be something like this:

```
  defineSpeciality(parameter) {
        for (var i=0; i<this.readyOffer.[parameter].length; i++) {
          output = output  + this.readyOffer.[parameter][i].name + ', '
        }
      return output
  },
```

but this of course does not work. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read, you should use the accessor (bracket) notation directly, without a `.` before:

```js
defineSpeciality(parameter) {
  for (var i=0; i < this.readyOffer[parameter].length; i++) {        // changed this line
    output = output + this.readyOffer[parameter][i].name + ', '      // changed this line
  }
  return output
},
```

Reference/recommended reading: [MDN - Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Comment: yes, this works!